# No display after connecting tv over HDMI on both tv and laptop screen

Tags: multiple-monitors, display, display-resolution

Yesterday I wanted to watch a movie on my tv so I plugged my TV to the HDMI port of my laptop. At first it didn't show my tv as a second screen so I went to settings -> display and enabled my tv. But after that step both my laptop screen and tv screen went black even after a reboot. 
I tried logging in with the guest account and in that account everything is working fine which seems like it is an user setting I messed up. Does someone know how I can reset this setting? 
What I managed to do is login into the broken account and start a shell by Super+T and use the `xrandr --query` command. The output of that is

```
Screen 0: minimum 320 x 200, current 1366 x 768, maximum 32767 x 32767
LVDS1 connected 1366x768+-32768+-32768 (normal left inverted right x
axis y axi$    1366x768       60.0*+    1360x768       59.8     60.0  
1024x768       60.0    800x600        60.3     56.2    640x480       
59.9 VGA1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) HDMI1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) DP1
disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) VIRTUAL1
disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
```

(Note I unplugged the tv by now)

I ran the same command on an other account and the output for that is the same except that LVDS1 states '1366*768+0+0'. I guess this last two parameters are some kind of offset, so I cannot see anything? I am running xubuntu.

Answer (score 1):

I managed to fix the issue by removing "~/.config/xfce4/xfconf/xfce-perchannel-xml/displays.xml".

Answer (score 0):

Recently I found below script somewhere on the net. Author claimed that it auto switch between hdmi and screen.

```
    #!/bin/bash

    # i ran `xrandr -q` to discover these values
    IN="eDP1"
    EXT="HDMI1"

    if (xrandr | grep "$EXT" | grep "+")
    then
    xrandr --output $EXT --off --output $IN --auto
    else
    if (xrandr | grep "$EXT" | grep " connected")
    then
    xrandr --output $IN --off --output $EXT --auto
      fi
    fi
```

I hope it works